# Issue when trying to login with Docusign API by official python lib on live account

Tags: python, docusignapi

I have issue when trying to login with API on live account, while on sandbox all works great.
When doing request on login, I must get on response data object `login_accounts`. Data in object looks like this(I've delete few symbols in password for sequrity reasons)

````
``` {'api_password': 'ZQQ+oSUO1alRWlCapJ0=',
 'login_accounts': [{'account_id': '4342454',
                     'account_id_guid': '6765dcc3-5dc6-4340-8240-9a53d3e728ab',
                     'base_url': 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/4342454',
                     'email': 'blahblahblah@gmail.com',
                     'is_default': 'true',
                     'login_account_settings': None,
                     'login_user_settings': None,
                     'name': 'Moonshot Capital',
                     'site_description': '',
                     'user_id': '1c960342-458b-4b33-b7ae-68ff9817bbb6',
                     'user_name': 'Here some name'}]}```
````

That was my sandbox data.
But in live account I've get only empty object

```
{'api_password': None, 'login_accounts': None}
```

If that was an error with login, I sould get something like 'bad auth' error code or something like this, but everywhere is 'http200 ok'. In system logs, that I can download from docusign service, I get only one error 404 on image object because in profile there no image, all other requests have code 'http200'. 
I thought that problem may be in integrator key and i've create another one, but it gives me same empty object. Also all my integration was working in free trial period on live account, and stops working after swithcing to BasicAPI billing plan.
I am using official python lib https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client
Here is my code sample

```
def setUp():
    # setting local configuration
    api_client = docusign.ApiClient(BASE_URL)
    oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri,
                                             oauth_base_url)
    try:
        api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename,
                                                    oauth_base_url,
                                                    integrator_key,
                                                    api_username, 3600)
        docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client
        return api_client
    except:
        logger.exception('')
        print(("If you login for first time please follow the url and give the"
               " access for app.\n"), oauth_login_url)


def docusign_login(api_client):
    auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
    try:
        login_info = auth_api.login(api_password='true',
                                    include_account_id_guid='true')
        assert login_info is not None
        assert len(login_info.login_accounts) > 0
        login_accounts = login_info.login_accounts
        assert login_accounts[0].account_id is not None
        logger.info(login_info)
        base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
        api_client.host = base_url
        docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client
        return login_accounts
    except ApiException:
        logger.exception('')

def request_signature_for_template(client_id):
    api_client = setUp()

    try:
        login_accounts = docusign_login(api_client)
        envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()
        envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(
            login_accounts[0].account_id,
            envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
```

Comment: Did you change the `BASE_URL` to not use the demo url `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/4342454`?

Comment: yes, of course i change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AuthenticationApi.login() method is intended to be used with Legacy Header authentication. For JWT/OAuth you would want to use the Get UserInfo method. Unfortunately, that method hasn't yet been implemented in the Python client. You'll need to make that call manually into the SDK is updated to include that functionality. Here's an example of that using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package.

```
oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com" #use account.docusign.com for Prod
api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

# using Requests to manually call userinfo endpoint
user_info_url = "https://" + oauth_base_url + "/oauth/userinfo"
request_auth_header = {'Authorization' : api_client.default_headers['Authorization']}
r = requests.get(user_info_url, headers=request_auth_header)

# parse response to pull default account
for a in r.json().get('accounts'):
    if a.get('is_default'): 
        account_id = a.get('account_id')
        new_base_url = a.get('base_uri') + "/restapi"

api_client.host = new_base_url
docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client
```